# Hook UIEvent into a custom Today Extension

Tags: ios8, today-extension

I am programming an iOS Today Extension with a `UITableView` in it. My idea is to load archived data from files when the extension is loaded, show the data on the UI, and also fetch the remote content in the `widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler`.

After the remote content is fetched, it will be saved in the local archive files, and call `reloadData` on the `UITableView`. 
The `UITableView` also responds to `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. When the user taps on one of the rows, it will launch Safari.

But I notice that when the extension is loaded, the system will use a previous snapshot instead of showing my UI. That is fine, I know it is for performance reasons. But the snapshot cannot take any UI event like `UITableView` does, it means users will have a delay since the see the extension until they can tap on each row.

Does anyone knows how to reduce the time that the snapshot is visible? It seems like Today doesn't invoke the `widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler` for extensions when the extension is loaded.

Here is the sample code I am using:

```cpp
@implementation TodayViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];     
    self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
    [self loadArchivedData];
    self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(0, self.stories.count * kCellHeight);

    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"RHNTodayCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"RHNTodayCell"];
}

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.stories.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    RHNTodayCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RHNTodayCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSDictionary *story = self.stories[indexPath.row];
    cell.titleLabel.text = story[@"title"];
    cell.scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)[story[@"score"] integerValue]];
    cell.commentLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)[story[@"kids"] count]];
    cell.nameLabel.text = story[@"by"];

    return cell;
}

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSDictionary *story = self.stories[indexPath.row];
    [self.extensionContext openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:story[@"url"]] completionHandler:nil];
}

- (void)widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NCUpdateResult))completionHandler {    

    completionHandler(NCUpdateResultNewData);
    [[RemoteAPI sharedClient] asyncFetchRemoteData:(NSArray *response) {
            [self saveArchiveFilesWithResponse: response];
            [self loadArchivedData];
            self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(0, self.stories.count * kCellHeight);
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            completionHandler(NCUpdateResultNewData);
    }];
}

@end
```

Comment: I have edited your question to improve the question grammar. One thing to note is that I've changed your personal pronouns, assuming that the user is male, which bothers some people. To further improve this question could you please include relevant code samples? It would make understanding what you are trying to do much clearer. I am not an iOS programmer, but with code samples and your explanation, I'm sure I could follow what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks @jamesMassey , I added sample code to make it clearer now.